# Windows Explorer preview pane image

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When I single-click on audio files in windows explorer, the image that is supposed to show up in the preview pane instead shows up in the middle of the screen and is in the way; I can't click on it to close it, I can only get rid of it by either exiting it from the taskbar, or clicking in white space in Windows explorer. It doesn't happen if the preview pane is off, but I like having it on so I'd prefer to not have to deactivate it. I have Windows 10.

Here's a screenshot of what happens:
imgur.com/a/Ynzng

Comment: Are you saying that what is supposed to appear inside the preview pane within the Explorer window is, instead, showing up in the middle of the screen regardless of it's boundary within the Explorer window? If you're able, a screenshot would probably help illustrate better.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ynzng

Answer (score -2):

Windows Explorer and Shell extensibility is fittingly here a feature of the Common Object Model.

You may try the approach of browsing the registry.  There may be a registry key with X, Y co ordinates set.